# How to draw a full screen quad and still see the objects behind it

Tags: opengl

I am creating a 3D game. I have objects in my game. When an enemy hits my position I want my screen to go red for a short time. I have chosen to do this by trying to render a full screen red square at my camera position. This is my attempt which is in my render method.

```
     RenderQuadTerrain();   

    //Draw the skybox
    CreateSkyBox(vNewPos.x,  vNewPos.y,  vNewPos.z,3500,3000,3500);
    DrawCoins();

    CollisionTest(g_Camera.Position().x, g_Camera.Position().y, g_Camera.Position().z);
    DrawEnemy();
    DrawEnemy1();

    //Draw SecondaryObjects models
    DrawSecondaryObjects(); 

    //Apply lighting effects
    LightingEffects();
    escapeAttempt();
if(hitbyenemy==true){
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE); // additive blending
float blendFactor = 1.0;
glColor3f(blendFactor ,0,0); // when blendFactor = 0, the quad won't be visible. When    blendFactor=1, the scene will be bathed in redness

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);                      // Draw A Quad
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);              // Top Left
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);              // Top Right
    glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);              // Bottom Right
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);              // Bottom Left
glEnd();
}
```

All this does, however, is turn all of the objects in my game a transparent colour, and I can't see the square anywhere. I don't even know how to position the quad. I'm very new to openGL.

How my game looks without an attempt to render a quad:
[image]

How my game looks after my attempt:
[image]

With Kevin's code and `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`;
[image]

EDIT: I have changed the code to the below paste..still looks like image 1.

http://pastebin.com/eiVFcQqM

Comment: Are you aware that even if your code works at the end, it will be using deprecated functionality? What you are trying to achieve here can be done much simpler using shaders.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this....is it really that much simpler? I heard shaders were more complex. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: They have steeper learning curve, but after you pass it, it will certainly be much more valuable knowledge. It's up to you to decide, I've struggled with old OpenGL for quite awhile before I "gave it a shot" ;) 
Anyway, that's a good place to start : http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible contributions to the problem:

- You probably want regular blending, not additive blending; additive blending will not turn white, yellow, or purple objects red. Change the blend func to `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` and use a color of `glColor4f(1, 0, 0, blendFactor);`
- You should `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` while drawing the overlay, to prevent it from being hidden by other geometry, and reenable it afterward (or use `glPush/PopAttrib(GL_ENABLE_BIT)`).
- The projection and modelview matrixes should be the identity, to ensure a quad with those coordinates covers the entire screen. (However, you may have that implicitly already, since you say it is affecting the full screen, just not in the right way.)

If these suggestions do not fix it, please edit your question showing screenshots of your game with and without the red flash so we can understand the problem better.

Comment: Your third picture looks like you didn't reenable depth test after disabling it. You should disable depth test only while you are rendering the red.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I have updated my post. Please check if I have enabled depth test appropriately.

Comment: @gurpsone You can't use glEnable inside glBegin..glEnd. GL should have reported an error  – you should be checking glGetError at least once in your rendering loop.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I have edited my code and have attached it in the paste bin link in the post. The game renders as normal but without a quad. Thanks for your help so far. Much appreciated.

Comment: @gurpsone (Please don't use external paste or image-hosting sites — we want to make sure questions and answers stay useful for years, which they won't if they expire.) I don't have any further ideas — I think you might need to ask someone to look at your entire code or work through it with more interaction, which isn't suitable for a question. You could see if anyone's interested in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19) — mention this question to get started.